# Calculating time in log file using python

Tags: python, date, date-manipulation

I have this log file (log.txt):

```
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  Start Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:01
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  Statement create or replace table amit (x date);
omer| (stmt : 0)| adminT|  Connection id - 0 - Executing - create or replace table amit (x date);
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  End Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:01
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  SQL - create or replace table amit (x date);
omer| (stmt : 0) | adminT|  Success
admin| (stmt : 1) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
admin| (stmt : 1) | adminT|  Start Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:14
admin| (stmt : 1) | adminT|  Statement create or replace table amit (x int, y int);
admin| (stmt : 1)| adminT|  Connection id - 0 - Executing - create or replace table amit (x int, y int);
admin| (stmt : 1) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
admin| (stmt : 1) | adminT|  End Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:15
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  Start Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:19
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  Statement create table amit (x int, y int);
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  Connection id - 0
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  End Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:22
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  SQL - Can't create table 'public.amit' - a table with the same name already exists
admin| (stmt : 2) | adminT|  Failed
```

and I want to calculate the statement that was the slowest successful statement for example:

`start time - 2018-11-06 16:52:01`
`End Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:01` the result is zero time and the statement at the end was `Success`

even though the last statement took 3 seconds it does not matter due to the fact that the statement failed in the end:
`Start Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:19` 
`End Time - 2018-11-06 16:52:22`
and `Failed` so it does not matter. 
so it comes that the middle statement took 1 second and was a success so this is the slowest statement.

I wish to implement this code using python that will produce the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the dates in date variables (you have to import 'datetime')

For example if you want to save 19.05.2020 9:00 then you need to code:

```
date = datetime.datetime(year=YOUR YEAR, month=YOUR Month, day=YOUR DAY, hour=YOUR HOUR {And so on})
```

and with the python function `min()` you can pass in multiple values and the function will return the smalest.
For example:

```
print(min(date - date1, date2 - date3, date4 - date5))
```